# What is the leading ? is F# type signature?

Tags: f#

When I hover certain methods that come from C# libraries in F#, some of the parameters start with a ?. I'm unfamiliar with this syntax. Does this mean nullable?

Here is an example from hovering the SetStatus method on the Activity class where the description parameter is preceded by a ?.
[image]

Comment: This is an optional parameter - please see here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/parameters-and-arguments#optional-parameters

Comment: Ah. I hadn't run across that in F#. I'm trying to wrap the SetStatus method in a regular F# function. So is the functional equivalent: setStatus code (description:option<string>)?

Comment: @PiotrRodak Would you like to post your comment as the answer? I can upvote and accept it.

Comment: I made it as answer, elaborating a bit more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The optional parameters in F# are declared with question marks in the declaration of the function:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/parameters-and-arguments#optional-parameters

What is interesting that the optionality expressed this way turns them to actual options of the base type, however there are differences: The options are 'active' only within the scope of the member method, and you have to pass the underlying type variable (or nothing in this case)

```ml
type Test() =
    member this.fn (?i : int) = 
        match i with
        | Some x -> -x
        | None -> 0
  
let t = new Test()

let r1 = t.fn()
printfn "%d" r1

let r2 = t.fn(4)
printfn "%d" r2
```

If you declare your member method as `int option`, you can't omit the parameter despite identical implementation of the method otherwise:

```ml
type Test() =

    member this.fn (i : int option) = 
        match i with
        | Some x -> -x
        | None -> 0
let t = new Test()

let r1 = t.fn()
printfn "%d" r1

let r2 = t.fn(4)
printfn "%d" r2
```

Here's the output:

```
/home/jdoodle.fs(9,14): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    'int option'    
but here has type
    'unit'    

/home/jdoodle.fs(12,15): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    'int option'    
but here has type
    'int'
```

In order to make it working, you have to pass int option to the method:

```ml
let r1 = t.fn(None)
printfn "%d" r1

let r2 = t.fn(Some 4)
printfn "%d" r
```

Comment: Very tricky. I'm sure this excellent explanation is going to save me so headaches later on.